# Append CDATA to a string

Tags: c#, xml, cdata

My situation is that we are using contract first method for web services. I have to use CDATA to avoid special characters, which needs to be appended to our current string variable. What would be the best method to append a CDATA tag to our current string, which is returned as xml element in response object? We are using C#.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [XCData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcdata.aspx) construct from the Linq-to-XML Library, which should automaticly wrap a CData tag around a string.

Example code:

```
//Assuming your string is called @string
XCData cdata = new XCData(@string);
//CData string
string cdataString = cdata.ToString();
```

If you do not have access to XLinq constructs you could just do the following

```
private string WrapInCData(string @string)
{
   return "<![CData[" + @string + "]]>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for he help. It was great

Comment: How do i convert back from xcdata into string, the wcf service returns back a string with cdata comments.